# CMD: Running a program gives me only the help page

Tags: shell, batch-file, cmd

I would like to convert the following pdf with `pdftooppm` from the `xpdfbin-win-3.04 package`.

I tried to put into the windows shell:

```
C:\Users\TestUser> C:/LocalData/TestUser/OCR/xpdfbin-win-3.04/xpdfbin-win-3.04/bin64/
pdftoppm -f 1 -l 10 -r 600 ocrbook Q:/Desktop/PDFs/Folder/Other Docus/convertThisPDF.pdf
```

However, I only get as a result the following:

```
pdftoppm version 3.04
Copyright 1996-2014 Glyph & Cog, LLC
Usage: pdftoppm [options] <PDF-file> <PPM-root>
  -f <int>          : first page to print
  -l <int>          : last page to print
  -r <int>          : resolution, in DPI (default is 150)
  -mono             : generate a monochrome PBM file
  -gray             : generate a grayscale PGM file
  -freetype <string>: enable FreeType font rasterizer: yes, no
  -aa <string>      : enable font anti-aliasing: yes, no
  -aaVector <string>: enable vector anti-aliasing: yes, no
  -opw <string>     : owner password (for encrypted files)
  -upw <string>     : user password (for encrypted files)
  -q                : don't print any messages or errors
  -cfg <string>     : configuration file to use in place of .xpdfrc
  -v                : print copyright and version info
  -h                : print usage information
  -help             : print usage information
  --help            : print usage information
  -?                : print usage information
```

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

PS.: I inverted the `\` because this code part is running in R.

Comment: Use double quotes `pdftoppm [options] "<PDF-file>" "<PPM-root>"`. What the `ocrbook` parameter stands for?

Comment: The help page says that the last parameter is supposed to be the `<PPM-root>`, In your case the last parameter is the name of the PDF file. Looks like you're simply using/invoking the tool wrong. Could it be that you just twisted the last two parameters (i.e. "ocrbook" should actually be the last parameter)?

Comment: @Christian.K Thx for your reply! Basically I am trying to implement the following script within R: [github script](https://gist.github.com/benmarwick/11333467). Honestly, it is still not clear to me what `ocrbook` might be. Hence, I am happy for every suggestion!

Comment: Many programs display the usage if they are invoked incorrectly. That's what's happening here. The -f -l and -r parameters look correct. So the only other two parameters are the pdf-file and the PPM-root, so Christian K is likely correct - swap the two. The other possibility I can think of is that usage text is wrong, in which case you'll just  have to find somebody or some discussion that explains what the real command line syntax is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others suggested, the problem is the order of your command line input. You need to specify the pdf file you want to convert and then provide a prefix for the ppm file that is output (ocrbook in your example).

`pdftoppm -f 2 -l 2 infile.pdf outfile_prefix`